# condition checking inside the foreach loop and printing multiple result with in one row

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have an array of  result after searching parameters,i want to print that result.while printing the result using foreach loop,i need to check the condition that ,if purchase dates are same, they should be printed in same row.How i can implement this?please help me.Thanks in advance

here is my code: ( i have get the result in controller and then i append the result in view)

```
foreach($res as $key => $row)
{


$i++;
$billfirst='';
$billend= $row['bill_date'];

if( $billfirst != $billend){

echo "<tr>
 <td class='txt'> ".$i."</td>
 <td class='txt'> ".$row['store']."</td>
<td class='txt'> ".$row['cust']."</td>
<td class='txt'> ".$row['name']."</td>
<td class='txt'> ".$row['net_amount']."</td>
<td class='txt'> ".$row['bill_date']."</td>

</tr>" ;

}
else {

echo "<tr><td class='txt'> ".$row['name']."</td>
<td class='txt'> ".$row['net_amount']."</td>
<td class='txt'> ".$row['bill_date']."</td>
</tr>";

}

$billfirst == $billend;
echo "</tbody></table>";

}
```

Comment: `foreach($res as $key => $row) enter code here{` ? what's this.... it's not valid PHP that's for sure.

Comment: Please explain it more. Did not understand clearly. what your expected results? please attach expected result as well.

Comment: var_dump($res)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make additional array to group your rows, example:

```
$arRows = array();
$billPrevious = "empty";
// save new grouped array
foreach($res as $key => $row) {
    $arRows[$row['bill_date']][] = $row;
}

// show groups - in the way you want to group it visually in table
foreach ($arRows as $key => $arGroup) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $arName = '';
    $arStore = '';
    foreach ($arGroup as $keyInGroup => $row) {
        $arName[] = $row['name'];
        $arStore[] = $row['store'];
    }
    echo '<td>'.implode('<br>', $arName).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.implode('<br>', $arStore).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```